# How to create a file from controller

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to save a file from a controller. It doesn't work using `fopen` and I'm unable to get the error message. Is there a way to do this or a absolutely need to use the filesystem bundle? And is there a way to understand the error? I used a try/catch blog with no luck. The code I'm using is really simple:

```
$file = $this->get('request')->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/myfile.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'file content');
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Does the user which run the web server has enough permissions to write in the directory?

Comment: You may try the [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-put-contents.php) function, maybe it will give you an error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot if way to do it. I use very often `__DIR__` to get the actual folder.

```
$fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/myfile.txt');
```

Its much easier if the file in the same folder. If you have an older PHP Version you have to use `dirname(__FILE__)`. Or in Symfony2 you can use some functions to get the directory. Something like this:

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
```

Comment: getting the directory is not a problem, the problem is I can't create the file and I don't know why. php is ver 5.4. thanks